# Python3 list string with double quotes(") changed into single(') why?

Tags: python-3.x, double-quotes

I define a list as friends = ["Ted", "Jim", "Sam"]
When I execute as `print(friends)`
I got result as 
['Ted', 'Jim', 'Sam']
Can anyone explain the reason as why python changed double quotes to single quotes?

Answer (score 1):

In memory it is just the contents of the string. When printed, double or single quotes are exactly the same, and one of them is chosen. Nothing remembers what was originally used, as that isn't relevant for anything.